# How two individual operators are parsed/evaluated while written together?

Tags: c

What's really happening behind?

```
int a=10,b=5,c=3;
b!=!a;
c=!!a;
```

Why the  values of `b` and `c` are 5 and 1 respectively?

Comment: Because `10 != 0`?

Comment: First result when googling for "c operators": http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm second result is Wikipedia.

Comment: This `b != !a;` does nothing, it's just a NOP.

Comment: This is just madcademic rubbish code.  Usefulness to future visitors?   Zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`b` is `5` because you've assigned it that value and never changed it, since

```
b!=!a;
```

...is just a condition that you don't do anything with, not any form of assignment.

`c` is `1` because `a` is `10` and `!10` is `0`, and `!0` is `1`, thus `!!a` is `1` (`a` is `10`).

Comment: Thank you for direct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You already have got [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36871358/2173917) to your question, but just to have a deeper look into *why* it happens that way, let me add my two cents here.

An expression like

```
 b!=!a;
```

is same as

```
b != !a;
```

because of the [maximal munch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch) rule used in the translation phase. Basically, this says that the longest possible token should be selected from the input while creating a construct (obviously, valid/ meaningful).

Following this principle the `!` and `=` are considered together to form the perfectly valid operator `!=` and the expression is parsed like

```
b != !a;
```

over

```
b ! = !a;  //or anything else.
```

That is why, there is no *assignment*, as you might have thought.

That said, `!` is an unary operator, which does not change the value of the operand. So, taken together, your code is essentially same as

```
int a=10,b=5,c=3;
c=!!a;  //double negation
```

so, `a` and `b` are unchanged, and `c` is `1` (because `!!10` == `!0` == `1` )